# Play framework import database

Tags: playframework

I'm new to the play framework, and having initially created a project, managing the creation of the tables through orm. Now changes have been made to the database, changes affecting the schema, then foreign keys and attributes have been introduced. I need to import the database with all its structure, and I would like to know if there is a way to align the code of my models based on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not clearly understand the question but you might need to study how to track and organize your database schema evolutions.
Please see here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Evolutions